# Interpolation of time series

Tags: c++

there eries of time range of Type DateTime in COM,but i need to fetch the maximum of fixed number of items from that series.How to interpolate this seris so that i can fetch fixed number of items

For example i have DATETIME collection of 1000 values from that i need to take only 20 values(including first and last record). what is the time span i need to check for iteration

```
DateTime time1 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 12, 10, 0, 0);
 DateTime time2 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 12, 27, 0, 0);

 int maxitems = 20;
 double dTimeSlices = Math.Floor((maxitems) / 2.0);
 double dTimeSpan = (time2.Ticks - time1.Ticks);
 double dSliceSpan = ts.Ticks / dTimeSlices;
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example i have DATETIME collection of 1000 values from that i need
>   to take only 20 values(including first and last record). what is the
>   time span i need to check for iteration

Interpolation acts on `discrete points`, not on `an entire series`.

There is no **time span** to **check for iteration**. The only relevant `timespan` is the **time between the 2 points being interpolated**.

If you want a fairly even collection/distribution of points within your 1000 point collection, look at how many points lie in the first 10% of the collection, the next 10%, etc. (choose whatever bracket makes sense, quarters, etc..) You will **interpolate to remove points in each bracket** until the **brackets are equal** and **you are at 20 values**. (Note a more proper way to reduce a set of 1000 to a group of 20 while minimizing any cumulative bias or error would be to fit a curve to the series of points and then you can pick any 20 points from the resulting curve to represent your set of 1000)

If, rather than reducing your set of 1000 down to 20 with an even distribution, all you care about is **picking 20 values** from the collection of 1000, then you will do essentially the same thing, except here, simply pick 20 pairs of values from a time that indicates an even spread of times throughout your collection of 1000 and interpolate each pair. That will give you 20 points within the data.

Hopefully this is clearer than mud.